# Orange Data Mining - File to NetworkFile

Tags: orange

I want to use Orange Data Mining to explore a network.  I have the data in a text-file.
For using the networkwidget I need to make a networkfile.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

This is the layout (sample)

Date|Person|From|To|Recipes|

03/10/2023|PersonA|PersonB|PersonA|Bread|

03/10/2023|PersonA|PersonA|PersonC|Bread|

04/10/2023|PersonB|PersonB|PersonC|Cookie|

In this case I should have 3 nodes that I can use in my exploration.

How do I convert this to a network file in Orange so that I can use the options of the Widget Network (Network Explorer, Network Analysis, Network Clustering)

I tried different import possibilities in Orange Data Mining:  File, Import Documents, Corpus, Text Files.

Answer (score 0):

The Network file widget will read Pajek network files.

See this page for format description: https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/pajek-net-format/

Comment: I know, but I can't find a widget that converts file into the pajekformat.

Comment: I do not think there is any that works from your type of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gephi to export Pajek (.net) files, then read the Pajek file into Orange (after you have installed the "Network" addon. Per Marko's comment, you simply use the "Network file" widget, then look for the .net file.